# Access forbidden Xampp Mac osx using yii2

Tags: php, macos, apache, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I get the following error:

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.
    If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
    Error 403

when I use the following code in my *httpd-vhosts.conf*:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName frontend.dev
DocumentRoot "AmanAgarwal/Projects/basic/yii-application/frontend/web/"

<Directory "AmanAgarwal/Projects/basic/yii-application/frontend/web/">
   # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
   RewriteEngine on
   # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
   RewriteRule . index.php

   # use index.php as index file
   DirectoryIndex index.php

   # ...other settings...
   # Apache 2.4
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from all
   Require all granted

   ## Apache 2.2

   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you run `init` with the console first?